# Legend has it... (a connect wall)

Tags: word, movies, connect-wall

#### Legend has it...

This is a two part [connect wall](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connect-wall) puzzle.  The sixteen movie and TV titles below can be arranged into groups of four that are related by a common theme.  The four themes themselves have a common theme, which is the final answer.

```
Aladdin (1992)
Beaches (1988)
Breakfast at Tiffany's (1961)   
Ghost (1990)
Gone with the Wind (1939)
Iron Man (2008)
Monk (2002)
Phantom of the Opera (2004)
Schindler's List (1993)
Sesame Street (1969)
Some Like It Hot (1959)
Star Wars: The Force Awakens (2015)
The Odd Couple (1970)
The Sound of Music (1965)
The Umbrella Academy (2019)
Titanic (1997)
```

Note 1: The years are provided to disambiguate in cases where multiple versions of the title exist.

Note 2: You will definitely need to use the internet to solve this, although I hope the themes can be guessed with only minimal research.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The categories:

> 1. **Tony** (thanks @Stiv!):
> Ghost (1990) - Tony Goldwyn
> Some Like it Hot (1959) - Tony Curtis
> The Odd Couple (1970) - Tony Randall
> Iron Man (2008) - Tony Stark
>  2. **Oscar**:
> Schindler's List (1993) - Oskar Schindler
> Sesame Street (1969) - Oscar the Grouch
> Star Wars: The Force Awakens (2015) - Oscar Isaac
> The Sound of Music (1965) - Oscar Hammerstein
>  3. **Grammy**:
> Beaches (1988) - "Wind Beneath My Wings" won a Grammy
> Titanic (1997) - "My Heart Will Go On" won a Grammy
> Breakfast at Tiffany's (1961) - "Moon River" won a Grammy
> Aladdin (1992) - "A Whole New World" won a Grammy
>  4. **Emmy**
> Phantom of the Opera (2004) - Emmy Rossum
> The Umbrella Academy (2019) - Emmy Raver-Lampman
> Monk (2002) - Emmy Clarke
> Gone With the Wind (1939) - Emmy Slattery

The main theme would be:

> **EGOT**, that is, having won Emmy, Grammy, Oscar and Tony awards. As the title says, (John) Legend has it.

Comment: Two of your categories have only odd-numbered years and the other two only even-numbered years ... coincidence?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Most definitely.

Comment: Think you're definitely on the right track now NudgeNudge! Over to you!

Comment: So that you don't waste too much time, Gone With the Wind is out of place (it was the most obscure clue to begin with)

Comment: @JS1 Thanks for that! It was obscure indeed, but I think it should be correct now?

Answer (score 3):

My current working solution has two groups in common with @NudgeNudge's (one member different), but a different third (and a missing fourth) and a different overall connection...

**Group 1**

> **Best Picture Oscar winners**
>
>  Gone with the Wind (1939)
>  The Sound of Music (1965)
>  Schindler's List (1993)
>  Titanic (1997)

**Group 2**

> **Takes place in Manhattan**
>
>  *Sesame Street (1969)* (different to @NudgeNudge)
>  Ghost (1990)
>  Breakfast at Tiffany's (1962)
>  Beaches (1988)

**Group 3**

> **Features an actor or main character called 'Tony'**
>
>  The Odd Couple (1970) - actor Tony Randall
>  Monk (2002) - actor Tony Shalhoub
>  Some Like It Hot (1959) - actor Tony Curtis
>  Iron Man (2008) - character Tony Stark

**Group 4**

> *Theme as yet unresolved*
>
>  Aladdin (1992)
>  Phantom of the Opera (2004)
>  Star Wars: The Force Awakens (2015)
>  The Umbrella Academy (2019)

**Final answer**

> **WEST SIDE STORY (1961)** - This film set in Manhattan won Best Picture and features a main character called Tony. I'm just struggling to spot a connection with the four as yet uncategorised films (possibly something Shakespearean, since West Side Story is based on Romeo and Juliet and Aladdin features a character called Iago?)...

Comment: 1 category correct, not all items in it correct (although they all fit, some items may fit into more than 1 category).  Compare with comment on NudgeNudge's answer for more info.

Comment: I thought you might have been on the right track with Group 3 because I also noticed that rot13(Tneel Znefunyy jnf vaibyirq jvgu obgu Ornpurf naq Gur Bqq Pbhcyr), but apparently not?